# Learning django with "Django from the Ground Up": Outdated?

Tags: django

I've discovered this excelent series of video-tutorials, the "Django from the Ground Up", but as it was uploaded on 09/08 I was wondering if it's still worth going through it or I will teach me and "outdated" way of working with django.

What do you think?

thanks in advance,
Ignacio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think teamtreehouse has some django videos (though I have never seen them), but I would suggest you purchase the django book written by the django creators "The Definitive Guide to Django: Web Development Done Right".  But be sure to get the second edition. You should also take a look at "http://harry.pythonanywhere.com/tutorial/1/" he has some very good tutorials you should work through. If however you really want videos try http://www.youtube.com/user/programmersbook he has has whole collection of django tutorials. The only downside on these is that the first 16 videos have no sound.
Anyway's good luck with django!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't watched the video, but I suspect it's out of date.

If the tutorial is from 2008, then it's probably based on Django 1.0. As I write this is 2012, the latest version is Django 1.4.

Django is pretty good at not breaking things between versions, however there are changes you have to make to get a 1.0 project working in 1.4. If you're new to Django, you might end up wasting a lot of time struggling with the changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alasdair. Then I'll continue searching for good sources to learn, as the tutorial is not enough for me... I'm looking for a bigger up built from scratch. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although I personally don't know "Django from the Ground Up", I would not suggest using 2-3 year old tutorials about in-depth parts of Django.

A large part of Django is still the same (forms for example), but a lot of cool things have been added/modified in the Django ORM and Django Admin. So it really depends on what you're learning. If it's a simple part or just an initial look than it would probably be a good starting point.

If you want in-depth knowledge than you will need something more recent.